# Profile graph considering different standard errors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics

I am trying to make a profile graph by introducing the standard error along with the average value for each of the times.
For some reason it is being assumed that the standard error is the same at each time (which is not true as you can see below). How can I introduce the correct standard error for each of the times in the graph below?

Codes:

```
library(PMCMR)
library(ExpDes.pt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tidyverse)

t1=tapply(dados$RespostaForca, dados$Tempo, describe)[[1]]$se
t2=tapply(dados$RespostaForca, dados$Tempo, describe)[[2]]$se
t3=tapply(dados$RespostaForca, dados$Tempo, describe)[[3]]$se
t4=tapply(dados$RespostaForca, dados$Tempo, describe)[[4]]$se
t5=tapply(dados$RespostaForca, dados$Tempo, describe)[[5]]$se
###########################################
####### Different standard errors #########
###########################################
standterr=c(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5); standterr

[1] 0.4326902 0.6871646 0.8456485 0.8299386 0.6416116


interact <- dados %>%
  select(RespostaForca, Tempo, Grupos) %>%
  group_by(Grupos, Tempo) %>%
  summarise(Average = mean(RespostaForca),
            y_se = psych::describe(dados$RespostaForca)$se)
###########################################
############### Graph #####################
###########################################
x11()
graf=ggplot(interact, aes(x=Tempo, y=Average)) + 
  ggtitle("") + geom_point(col="black", size=2, aes(shape=Grupos)) +  
  geom_line(aes(color=Grupos),size=1.1) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Average-1.96*y_se, 
                    ymax = Average+1.96*y_se),
                width = .1) +
  labs(fill="Grupos: ", x="Tempo", 
                     y="Força de Retenção (N)") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1B9E77","#D95F02")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 22),legend.text = element_text(size = 22),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 22),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 25)) 
graf+scale_color_manual(values=c("black","#D95F02", "#56B4E9"))
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. The issue is related to using `dados$RespostaForca` as you are getting a constant, instead only place the variable:

```
library(PMCMR)
library(ExpDes.pt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tidyverse)
#Data
dados <- read.delim('data.csv',stringsAsFactors = F,sep=';')
#Process
interact <- dados %>%
  select(RespostaForca, Tempo, Grupos) %>%
  group_by(Grupos, Tempo) %>%
  summarise(Average = mean(RespostaForca),
            y_se = psych::describe(RespostaForca)$se)
#Plot
ggplot(interact, aes(x=Tempo, y=Average)) + 
  ggtitle("") + geom_point(col="black", size=2, aes(shape=Grupos)) +  
  geom_line(aes(color=Grupos),size=1.1) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Average-1.96*y_se, 
                    ymax = Average+1.96*y_se),
                width = .1) +
  labs(fill="Grupos: ", x="Tempo", 
       y="Força de Retenção (N)") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1B9E77","#D95F02")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 22),legend.text = element_text(size = 22),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 22),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 25)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","#D95F02", "#56B4E9"))
```

Output:

[image]